Compile DEX from Android project using Android Gradle plugin APIs
I am developing a Gradle plugin that manages Android subprojects. This plugin applies the Android Gradle plugin to each subproject to support Android-specific builds. My plugin also defines a task that depends on assembleRelease to extract the DEX files from the final APK and share them as Gradle configuration artifacts for further use.
However, relying on assembleRelease introduces unnecessary overhead, as it performs tasks I don't need, such as asset building and resource packaging. My primary goal is to obtain the DEX file, so invoking the entire assembleRelease task is inefficient.
To optimize my plugin, I am considering using internal APIs from the Android Gradle plugin or the D8 compiler library to compile only the DEX files and bypass other steps in assembleRelease that are irrelevant to my needs.
Could anyone suggest specific internal APIs or alternative approaches to achieve this?
